# Why constructors are pass by reference in Java?

Tags: java

In java all methods are pass by value.But today i learnt that constructors are pass by reference.

```
// Attack the internals of a Period instance
Date start = new Date();
Date end = new Date();
Period p = new Period(start, end);
end.setYear(78);  // Modifies internals of p!
```

This works and is able to edit the private fields.

What is the reason of this decision? or am i missing something?

Comment: all objects always passes by reference, but simple datatypes passes by value for example `78` in your code

Comment: Welcome to the world of inadvert mutation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work same way for other method. Actually reference is passed by value.

```
Class A{
   B b;
   void setB(B b) {
       this.b = b;
   }
};

A a;
B b;
A.setB(b);

b.change(); //changed in A
```

What it means that reference is passed by value?

```
void f(A a) {
    a.change(); // caller will see that object is changed. We change it using reference
    a = new A(); // we change the value of refernce. No changes are visible outside the function
    a.change(); //new object is changing. No changes are visible outside the function
}
```

Basically you just pass address of object (integer) by value. Everything is integer. Your class contains integer. And it didn't change. The objects on that address did.

Comment: +1 for nice example. As a side note, some people don't realise you can declare parameters final i.e. `f(final A a){ ... }` this ensures that you don't inadvertently override a - not that this is very relevant to this discussion.

Answer (score 8):

You've got that wrong:

> In java all methods are pass by value.

Instead: In Java all parameters are passed by value, even references are passed by value.

You don't "pass objects", only references to objects. This is the same for methods and constructors.

So

```
end.setYear(78);  // Modifies internals of p!
```

does not change the reference but only the object the reference points to.

Answer (score 1):

the mechanism is same for both constructor and method. From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into
>   methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the
>   passed-in reference still references the same object as before.
>   However, the values of the object's fields can be changed in the
>   method, if they have the proper access level

Answer (score 1):

No, you aren't changing any private fields. The private fields in Period are not touched, they still reference the same object. Unfortunatly, a Date object is mutable. So you see the mutation through the Period object.

If you want to avoid this, make a copy of each object passed in the constructor, only thus you'll have your own Date objects no one outside of Period can modify.

Comment: I already met this example at "Item 39: Make defensive copies when needed" on Effective Java 2

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with only references,not objects.

The classic definition of pass by value.

*The value of a reference variable is an "address" in Java. When you pass a reference variable to a method, a new reference variable is placed on the stack and a copy of the passed reference variable's value is used to initialize the new local **reference varaible's value, just like any primitive type.***

**NOTE**: While you can think of the reference as a memory address, it's not. The underlying mechanism makes it act logically as if it were though.

**SHORT VERSION**: references are simple variables just like the other primitive types for purposes of passing arguments to methods. What you can do with them once passed is obviously different.

Comment: Of course it is a memory address. What else?

Comment: My intention is to convey the message reference is also passing by value only :)